# Android In-App Billing - Multiple SKUs in Cart

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am developing an android application for my music school teacher who wants to sell his music arrangements of Indian Film Music in PDF format to be played by piano players. I have designed a list view of songs with each item in the list giving an option for the user to add/remove music sheets to/from cart.

I have created my google console developer account and attached a merchant account to it. I have created managed in-app products for each of the music sheets available in my application.

The data for each of the list item are created from the below Song class

```
public class Song {
    private String songID;
    private int filmImageID;
    private String songName;
    private String movieName;
    private String composerName;
    private String yearReleased;
    private int songPrice;  
    private int mp3File;    
    private Boolean isPlaying;
    private Boolean inCart; 

    public Song(String songID, int filmImageID, String songName, String movieName, String composerName,
            String yearReleased, int songPrice, int mp3File, Boolean isPlaying, Boolean inCart) {
        super();
        this.songID = songID;
        this.filmImageID = filmImageID;
        this.movieName = movieName;
        this.songName = songName;
        this.composerName = composerName;
        this.yearReleased = yearReleased;
        this.songPrice = songPrice;
        this.mp3File = mp3File;     
        this.isPlaying=isPlaying;
        this.inCart=inCart;
    }
```

I have created an ArrayList of type Song class and added objects to it as mentioned below

```
private ArrayList<Song> songsList = new ArrayList<Song>();
songsList.add(new Song("song1_v1",R.drawable.msv_periya_idhuthu_pen,"Andru Vandhadhum Adhey Nila","Periya Idhuthu Pen","M.S. Viswanathan","1963",250,R.raw.msv_andru_vanthathum_athe_nila_pip_1963_200,false,false));
        songsList.add(new Song("song22_v2",R.drawable.msv_paalum_pazhamum,"Aalaiya Maniyin Oosai","Paalum Pazhamum","M.S. Viswanathan","1961",120,R.raw.msv_aalayamaniyin_oosai_pp_1961_120,false,false));
```

The variable songID in the class Song holds the Product ID as I mentioned in my in-app products list of my google console developer account.

I have initiated my connection to GooglePlay using the onCreate() method of MusicSheets.java as shown below

```
mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {           
    @Override
    public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            if(!result.isSuccess()){
                Toast.makeText(MusicSheets.this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            Toast.makeText(MusicSheets.this, "Pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

There is an ImageView named imgPayNow to carry out the purchase after the user selects the required music sheets. The code for the imgPayNow is given below

```
imgPayNow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPayNow);
imgPayNow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(cartList.size()<1){
            Toast.makeText(MusicSheets.this, "Your cart is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {               

            @Override
            public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase info) {
                if (result.isFailure()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MusicSheets.this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }   
            }
        };

        for(int i=0;i<cartList.size();i++){
            if (mHelper != null) mHelper.flagEndAsync();
            mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(MusicSheets.this, cartList.get(i), 10001, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
        }
    }
});
```

Now the problem I face with the above coding is that, the launchPurchaseFlow method is called for the number of items added to the cart as I am using a For loop. I cannot think of a logic on how to handle multiple SKUs in launchPurchaseFlow method.

Sorry for the silly question being asked. I am an amateur android developer. Please help me to get through this.

Thanks,
Srini

Comment: Haven't worked with in-app purchasing in quite a while, however, AFAIK, bulk purchasing is not yet supported and you have to invoke `launchPurchaseFlow` for each individual item

Comment: Hi Jay Soyer, I have raised a question for javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException? Can you please answer for it?